# Localhost Leads to 404 with DNSMasq Setup and custom Vhost

Tags: apache, dns, osx-yosemite, dnsmasq

I have configured DNSMasq to work for an OSX Yosemite local test server with native Apache2, native PHP5 and homebrew MySQL and DNSMasq. It is all working now, but with the current DNS setup I can only access PHPMyAdmin in its configuration for host using 127.0.0.1 and the same goes for every WordPress setup. Host has to be 127.0.0.1 Localhost is no longer working to access my local host.

Here some of the configurations I have:

`/etc/hosts` :

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Resolver `/etc/resolver/dev` :

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

In `/usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf` I added:

```
listen-address=127.0.0.1
address=/dev/127.0.0.1
```

Now when I load localhost or `http://localhost` I get a 404:

```
::1 - - [22/Feb/2015:08:12:33 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 198
```

Pinging works just fine:

```
ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.050 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.106 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.116 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.113 ms
^C
--- localhost ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.050/0.096/0.116/0.027 ms
```

And my VirtualHost in `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/me/webdesign/%1"
ServerName vhosts.dev
ServerAlias *.dev
UseCanonicalName Off
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
ErrorLog "/Users/me/webdesign/vhosts-error_log"
<Directory "/Users/me/webdesign/*">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

In this in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` I have added to the end to stop an error on starting Apache and to make PHPMYAdmin work on localhost.

```
ServerName localhost
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/local/share/phpmyadmin/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      Require all granted
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

And when I run scutil I see

```
scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : Home
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.1.1
  if_index : 4 (en1)
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address

resolver #2
  domain   : dev
  nameserver[0] : 127.0.0.1
  flags    : Request A records, Request AAAA records
  reach    : Reachable,Local Address

DNS configuration (for scoped queries)

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : Home
  nameserver[0] : 192.168.1.1
  if_index : 4 (en1)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : Reachable,Directly Reachable Address
```

Any ideas how I can make localhost work again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/set-virtual-hosts-apache-mac-osx-10-9-mavericks-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/) that when you add a new DocumentRoot you lose the older one used by localhost. So I added

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerName localhost 
DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

to show it the way. Now localhost works again. For sites served under .dev 127.0.0.1 is still needed though.